# VSTS Coder Coverage is not showing HTML report

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to configure VSTS Build to run our Integration tests and generate the code coverage HTML report. I am using Coverlet and ReportGenerator plugin to accomplish this. This is how I have my build configured right now:

```
    pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.7.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.7.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Integration Tests'
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration)  /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\ --no-build'

- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@1
  displayName: ReportGenerator
  inputs:
    reports: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\coverage.cobertura.xml'
    targetdir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coveragereport'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coveragereport\Cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)\src\target\reports\coverage'

- task: PublishSymbols@1
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

I am not sure where I am making the mistake, but the build seems to complete without any errors and still I do not see anything in the code coverage tab. Can you please explain what am I missing?

Comment: i didnt know about that extension, I have tests in python\c++\dotnetcore and it doesnt work for any of them without the extension. I'll try with that extension (https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/azure-devops-code-coverage/), thanks!

Comment: same thing for me, build is green, but actual logs shows this: `Error during reading report 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\32ee6e7b-2ca9-4ce0-8636-10c008200390\VssAdministrator_fv-az413_2019-04-03.18_29_35.coverage' (Size: 33MB): Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

Comment: I'd love to know if you found the source of the "Data at the root level is invalid". That's usually a sign of a byte order marker at the beginning of the file, but since the generation of the file is mostly out of our control, what can we do about it? Add a custom step to strip the BOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was finally able to resolve the issues with the help of this post

https://www.meziantou.net/2019/02/18/computing-code-coverage-for-a-net-core-project-with-azure-devops-and-coverlet

Turns out if you read very carefully then the **"Target Directory"** of the Report Generator step needs to match the **"Report Directory"** of the Publish CodeCoverage Results task. If you look at my original question they were different because my understanding was incorrect. Once I fixed the paths, the code coverage started showing in the build code coverage tab. Hope it helps someone facing the same issue.